# Type '{id: number; ...}' is not assignable to type void | Chainable<any>

Tags: typescript, cypress

We just recently started migrating from JS to typescript in our Cypress project.

I have a custom command:

```js
export {}

declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            getInfo(body: object): Chainable<any>
        }
    }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('getInfo', (body: object) => {
    let info: {
        id: number;
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string
    } = {
        id: 0,
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
    }

    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/order',
        body: body
    }).then(response => {
            info.id = response.body.customer.id
            info.firstName = response.body.customer.firstName
            info.lastName = response.body.customer.lastName
        })

    return info
})
```

Unfortunately I get an underline error on the `(body: object) => {` portion

Error is as follows:

```
Argument of type '(body: object) => { id: number; firstName: string; lastName: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CommandFn<\"getInfo\">'.\n  Type '{ id: number; firstName: string; lastName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'void | Chainable<any>'
```

What am I possibly doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the typescript POV you should be able to `return cy.wrap(info)` to make the return type as `Chainable<any>`.

But another problem is delay in `cy.request({...})` resolving probably means the value returned is the empty `info` object.

Try this instead

```js
export {}

declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            getInfo(body: object): Chainable<any>
        }
    }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('getInfo', (body: object) => {

    // return the request here so that the response is awaited

    return cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/order',
        body: body
    }).then(response => {

        let info: {
          id: number;
          firstName: string;
          lastName: string
        } = {
          id: response.body.customer.id,
          firstName: response.body.customer.firstName,
          lastName: response.body.customer.lastName
        }

        // return the info here so that the response is modified 
        return info  
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[Lowercase 'o' object is a primitive in JS/TS](https://2ality.com/2020/01/typing-objects-typescript.html#object-vs.-object-in-typescript), and doesn't behave the way that you are trying to use it. A quick fix would probably be to type `body` as Uppercase 'O' `Object`.

Additionally, if `body` is going to be of the same type as the `info` variable, you could make a custom type.

```js
interface Info {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

Cypress.Commands.add('getInfo', (body: Info) => {
  const info: Info = {
    id: 0,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
  };

  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/order',
    body
  }).then((response) => {
    info.id = response.body.customer.id;
    info.firstName = response.body.customer.firstName;
    info.lastName = response.body.customer.lastName;
  });

  return info;
});
```

When in doubt, always try to type your variables as much as possible, and then start working backwards to get to the "simplest" implementation.

Comment: I tried to implement this same code plus my `declare global` code. I still get the "Type 'Info' is not assignable to type 'void | Chainable<any>'"

Comment: How are you defining this in the namespace?

Comment: I may have forgotten to include cy.wrap to my object return that's why I am getting said error.